# Yii2 Textbox in Gridview

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

how can i save this value to database? 
can anyone help me? 
im using SqlDataProvider for the GridView, it doesnt have id on it. 
[the checkbox is only 1 of those. and the textbox is optional only.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8YjJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX and send information to the controller/action and save value

Comment: im not really familiar to ajax.